# Nemo file manager: How can I change font color of folder names in toolbar button?

Tags: fonts, colors, filemanager, button, nemo

How can I change font color of folder names in the toolbar button in Nemo file manager?

Because I strongly prefer Ambiance theme, I want to keep it, but it messes up the theme of Nemo which is my favourite file manager as shown.

How can I specifically tweak just folder name fonts color of Nemo? Is there a way without recompiling the whole app?

[image: Nemo - Ambiance-theme-not-so-fit-in font color on Folder name's button]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try the following:

**1)** Open your favorite editor. (eg:*gedit*) and create a new file named **nemo.css**, add these lines:

```
/* font path bar */
.nemo-pathbar-button,    
NemoPathbarButton {
    color: #4c4c4c;
}
```

[image]

Add your favorite color in hexadecimal notation. I choose **#4c4c4c** *(Grey color)*

[image]

**2)** Save the file `nemo.css` in your Desktop.

**3)** Open a Terminal and type:

- `sudo cp /home/*your_user*/Desktop/nemo.css /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/apps/`

**4)** Go to the `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/apps/` directory, and change the perms of the file.

- `cd /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/apps`
- `sudo chmod 644 nemo.css`

**5)** Edit the *gtk.css*  to import the `nemo.css`, and add a line:

```
 sudo -H gedit /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
```

add

```
 @import url("apps/nemo.css");
```

[image]

**6)** Kill nemo with (`pkill nemo`) or just Logout and Login to see the changes.

In my case:

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks. Where do you get to know the names of the elements for the CSS? I need to change the colour of the free space barcharts (because free and used are the [same colour](http://askubuntu.com/questions/463761/how-to-fix-gtk-theme-for-nemo)!) so I need to know what CSS selectors to use to target those. Thanks.

Comment: @artfulrobot: you can get the names of the widget, classes etc from the nemo-style-fallback.css file. https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/blob/master/src/nemo-style-fallback.css

Comment: Thank you! I've solved my problem! (will post answer in a mo)

Answer (score 5):

Some good soul created a [git repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7n5a.jpg) for that problem

Run the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/alsar/ubuntu-ambiance-nemo
cd ubuntu-ambiance-nemo/
./install.sh
nemo -q
```

Than Nemo will look as it should:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Thanks. Because of your guide about importing customized Stylesheet, I found [this guide](http://segfault.linuxmint.com/2013/05/nemo-1-8-and-gtk-themes/)

Code goes:

```
.nemo-pathbar-button,
NemoPathbarButton {
background-image: -gtk-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,
color-stop (0, shade(@dark_bg_color, 1.1)),
color-stop (.3, shade(@dark_bg_color, 1.1)),
color-stop (.7, shade(@dark_bg_color, 0.90)),
color-stop (1, shade(@dark_bg_color, 0.80)));
border-color: shade(@dark_bg_color, 0.7);
-NemoPathbarButton-border-radius: 3px;
}

NemoPathbarButton:active {
background-image: -gtk-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,
color-stop (0, shade(@dark_bg_color, .8)),
color-stop (.3, shade(@dark_bg_color, .9)),
color-stop (1, shade(@dark_bg_color, 1.0)));
border-color: shade(@dark_bg_color, 0.7);
}

NemoPathbarButton:hover {
background-image: -gtk-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,
color-stop (0, shade(alpha(@dark_bg_color, 1.4), 1.25)),
color-stop (.3, shade(alpha(@dark_bg_color, 1.4), 1.25)),
color-stop (.7, shade(alpha(@dark_bg_color, 1.4), 0.95)),
color-stop (1, shade(alpha(@dark_bg_color, 1.4), 0.85)));
border-color: shade(@dark_bg_color, 0.7);
}
```

[image: Better look of Nemo with Ambiance]