# Nautilus crashes with "'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed" / "totem-video-thumbnailer couldn't open file"

Tags: nautilus, 13.10

Whenever I open nautilus it crashes and I get this error in terminal.  i am running saucy.  does anybody know of a different file manger that i can install?

```
sys:1: Warning: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
totem-video-thumbnailer couldn't open file 'file:///home/bruce/New%20Project.ogv'

sys:1: Warning: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: I got the same g_object errors and problem was about this: [Launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1203349) / Different file manager? ["Good old Nautilus" fork Nemo](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html)

Comment: I advise you to install [Nemo][1], Nautilus is not a file manager anymore.


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/360831/downgrade-to-nautilus-3-4-from-ubuntu-13-10-nautilus-3-8/365206#365206

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also deleting or renaming the file mentioned in error from a terminal.

i.e.

```
sys:1: Warning: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
totem-video-thumbnailer couldn't open file 'file:///home/bruce/New%20Project.ogv'

rm -rf "/home/bruce/New Project.ogv"
```

or

```
mv "/home/bruce/New Project.ogv" "/home/bruce/NewName.ogv"
```

Then start nautilus or gnome-shell etc again without error

Comment: If this was meant as an actual answer, then please edit your post to make that more clear. If not, then please use post answer only for actual answer. You will be able to post comments if you invest a little time in the site.

Answer (score 2):

I fix it by moving Extensions in a temporary folder

```
sudo mv /usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions /tmp
```

After that try a relaunch of Nautilus and replace extension one by one in the Extension folder

Comment: Moving to `/tmp` could be dangerous.