# How to jump to file in folder based on starting letter

Tags: filesystem, navigation

Let say I have a folder with several subfolders[image]
How can I quickly select the folder `NATUR`. In OS X I can just hit `n` on my keyboard and it jumps to `NATUR`. What is the equivalent in Ubuntu?

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I am on ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu 13.04 or Ubuntu 13.10, you won't be able to jump directly to the file when you type the first few characters of its name, instead it will search recursively to find files/folders similar to what you type.

This search feature came up in nautilus 3.8 and you would have an option of choosing between the recursive search and the earlier "type-ahead" search only in Ubuntu 14.04. <sup>[[1]](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/01/ubuntu-14-04-nautilus-type-ahead-patch)</sup>

Untill then if you want to enable the "type-ahead" feature, you may want to look at this answer:

- [Downgrade to Nautilus 3.4 from Ubuntu 13.10 / Nautilus 3.8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360831/downgrade-to-nautilus-3-4-from-ubuntu-13-10-nautilus-3-8/365206#365206)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version you use but in 12.xx, you can just start typing the name and Ubuntu will automatically select the folder which corresponds with what you typed.

IE:
nat will select the folder NATUR

Comment: Looking at the screenshot, it doesn't seem like its older than 13.xx