# How to fix GTK theme for Nemo's pathbar breadcrumbs and disk free space barchart

Tags: themes, nemo

I like a few features of Nemo, but there seems to be a theme problem - at least when running under Ubuntu Gnome 14.04:

As you can see from this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

it's not possible to see which of the breadcrumbs is selected, and the barchart for available space seems to be colouring both full and free the same colour!

In the screenshot I have the "global dark theme" on, but it's the same problem without this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I installed Nemo from the [Mint packaged for Ubuntu archives](http://www.noobslab.com/2013/10/nemo-file-manager-with-extensions-for.html). This updated it, made some more nemo-* packages available and fixed the breadcrumbs, but I was left with the useless disk space indicators. Here's how I fixed those:

### Create your own GTK+3 theme as follows

First, duplicate the Adwaita theme with the name Adwaita-custom

```
$ cd /usr/share/themes
$ sudo bash  # easier than prepending every line with sudo...
# cp -ar Adwaita Adwaita-custom
# cd Adwaita-custom
# sed -i 's/Adwaita/Adwaita-custom/' index.theme
```

Now we add special CSS for Nemo

```
# cd gtk-3.0
# echo '@import url("apps/nemo-custom.css");' >>gtk.css
# mkdir apps
# $EDITOR apps/nemo-custom.css*
```

Now in that file, here's what I put:

```
/* For Places Sidebar diskfull indicators */

NemoPlacesTreeView {
    -NemoPlacesTreeView-disk-full-bg-color: #d9d9d9;
    -NemoPlacesTreeView-disk-full-fg-color: #4a90d9 ;
    -NemoPlacesTreeView-disk-full-bar-width: 2px;
    -NemoPlacesTreeView-disk-full-bar-radius: 1px;
    -NemoPlacesTreeView-disk-full-bottom-padding: 1px;
    -NemoPlacesTreeView-disk-full-max-length: 70px;
}

NemoPlacesTreeView:selected {
    -NemoPlacesTreeView-disk-full-bg-color: #d9d9d9;
    -NemoPlacesTreeView-disk-full-fg-color: shade(#4a90d9,0.5) ;
}
```

Save and exit your editor. You can now drop root privileges, too, and/or exit your terminal shell.

**Now select Adwaita-custom** as the GTK+ theme in the tweak tool ("Advanced Settings") app.

Here's mine now:
[image: screenshot]

PS. Big thanks to Roman Raguet for [the comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/328520/about-nemo-file-manager-how-can-i-change-font-color-of-folder-name-in-toolbar-b/328631?noredirect=1#comment615329_328631) which linked to the [original nemo css](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/blob/master/src/nemo-style-fallback.css).

PPS. Oh, in my screenshot, you like my small titlebar eh? Yeah, nice. [Here's how](https://artfulrobot.uk/blog/ubuntu-gnome-1404-trusty-initial-review).

Comment: How did you know what styles to edit?

Comment: @seth Happy Christmas! Um, well I kinda just looked through the file for something that sounded related. `disk-full` was a bit of a give-away ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! SInce the custom theme did not appear in the theme list in the System Settings dialogue, I used Unity Tweak Tool (https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/) to select the custom theme.

Comment: @artfulrobot Dead links on this answer

Comment: @Psionman not surprised, it's 6 years old. Fixed the last one for what that's worth, but I'd imagine all this is very out of date now.

Comment: @artfulrobot I know, but I looked at it and thought it worth following the links. Some questions are still with us :)