# How can I customize Nemo file manager?

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, themes, gtk, nemo

On my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS system, I replaced Nautilus with Nemo 4.2.3, because it has more useful features. However I had to admit that Nautilus "skin/theme" is more beautiful to me, when I use Ambiance theme.

I would like to customize Nemo skin to be similar like Nautilus, including the gray sidebar.

I made a comparison:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open a terminal window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>
2. `cd ~/.config/gtk-3.0/`
3. `gedit gtk.css` *(gets created if it doesn't exits)*
4. Add the following code:

```
/*.nemo-places-sidebar .view { */ 
.nemo-window .sidebar .view {
  background-color: @theme_fg_color;
  color: @theme_bg_color;
}
```

5. Save file and close gedit
6. Quit/close all nemo windows `nemo -q`
7. Startup a nemo file explorer `nemo`

[image: Pre Modification][image: Post Modification]

8. After you close the Nemo window you will notice that the started process in the terminal window is still active. It will close automatically after 30 seconds, or you could force close it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.
9. Tune to your liking...

---

I made reference to my theme defined colors in this example, an inverted their "normal use", but you can put directly an html color code if you prefer:

```
.nemo-window .sidebar .view {
  background-color: #605e54;
  color: #e5e5e5;
}
```

This method is **Theme independent**, *unless ofcourse you make reference to theme colors*. You can comment out with `/* .... */` things you have in the `gtk.css` file if you don't want it to override the "default" settings or just delete the file.

---

### Other CSS Properties:

First have a read through [Overview of CSS in GTK+](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-css-overview.html) to understand how these styles are formed.

I would recommend to investigate source code of themes to see if they have any Nemo specific sections such as [here](https://github.com/vinceliuice/Matcha-gtk-theme/blob/master/src/gtk-3.0/sass/apps/_misc.scss) or [here].(https://github.com/linuxmint/mint-themes/blob/712039deb45e465c28dd4c27f65745e7dfb09c9a/src/Mint-Y/gtk-3.0/sass/_applications.scss#L241)

[*GtkStyleContextClass* Constant def](https://github.com/linuxmint/gtk/blob/master/gtk/gtkstylecontext.h) List properties that will be in the code as constants. May help in decifering some of it in a specific region of interest.

A lot will probably be inherited names as they will grab classifiers from common theme names, yet a search for [`gtk_style_context_add_class` in the github repository](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/search?q=gtk_style_context_add_class) brings a couple "new" names in sight.

```
src/nemo-config-base-widget.c --> `view`, `primary-toolbar`
src/nemo-properties-window.c --> `primary-toolbar`, `raised`
libnemo-private/nemo-places-tree-view.c --> `places-treeview`
src/nemo-trash-bar.c --> `nemo-cluebar-label`
src/nemo-floating-bar.c --> `floating-bar`
src/nemo-desktop-window.c --> `nemo-desktop-window`,
libnemo-private/nemo-icon-container.c --> `nemo-desktop`
src/nemo-pathbar.c --> `slider-button`
src/nemo-window-pane.c --> `nemo-inactive-pane`
libnemo-private/nemo-icon-canvas-item.c --> `nemo-canvas-item`, `dim-label`
libnemo-private/nemo-tree-view-drag-dest.c --> `treeview-drop-indicator`
src/nemo-window.c --> `nemo-window`
src/nemo-places-sidebar.c --> `nemo-places-sidebar`
```

### Examples:

https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/blob/master/gresources/nemo-style-fallback.css
https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/blob/master/gresources/nemo-style-fallback-mandatory.css
https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/blob/master/gresources/nemo-style-application.css

### My Investigation:

I had a look into some [code from Nemo](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/blob/52efe6f3c4e22deccefc7653a11c2f413f42b3dc/src/nemo-application.c#L103) and found that it was making calls to css-providers. Then "duckling" *(don't know what to call "googling" through duckduckgo xD)* similar search terms found [this bit of code](https://gtk-rs.org/docs/src/gtk/auto/css_provider.rs.html) which has within the comments:

> ... certain files will be read when GTK+ is initialized.
>
> First, the file `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` is loaded if it exists.
>
> Then, GTK+ loads the first existing file among `XDG_DATA_HOME/themes/THEME/gtk-VERSION/gtk.css`, `$HOME/.themes/THEME/gtk-VERSION/gtk.css`, `$XDG_DATA_DIRS/themes/THEME/gtk-VERSION/gtk.css` and `DATADIR/share/themes/THEME/gtk-VERSION/gtk.css`, where `THEME` is the name of the current theme (see the `Settings:gtk-theme-name` setting), `DATADIR` is the prefix configured when GTK+ was compiled (unless overridden by the `GTK_DATA_PREFIX` environment variable), and `VERSION` is the GTK+ version number. If no file is found for the current version, GTK+ tries older versions all the way back to 3.0.

So I went to `~/.config/gtk-3.0/` to only find a file named `bookmarks`

some more searching landed me to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/topolik/3ba9a76511ba40df1ccb9ef1b61c1fc5) and the search continues to all of the following resources:

[a](https://www.puolanka.org/goto/how-to-change-nemos-background-color/)
,[b](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261156/editing-yaru-gtk-theme-where-is-resource-com-ubuntu-themes-yaru-3-20-gtk-css)
,[c](https://askubuntu.com/questions/328520/nemo-file-manager-how-can-i-change-font-color-of-folder-names-in-toolbar-button)
,[d](https://github.com/linuxmint/mint-themes/blob/712039deb45e465c28dd4c27f65745e7dfb09c9a/src/Mint-Y/gtk-3.0/sass/_applications.scss#L241)
,[e](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/issues/2276#issuecomment-569777928)
,[f](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463761/how-to-fix-gtk-theme-for-nemos-pathbar-breadcrumbs-and-disk-free-space-barchart)
,[g](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463761/how-to-fix-gtk-theme-for-nemos-pathbar-breadcrumbs-and-disk-free-space-barchart)
,[h](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-css-properties.html)
,[i](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1701842#p1701842)