# Editing Yaru Gtk theme: where is resource:///com/ubuntu/themes/Yaru/3.20/gtk.css?

Tags: themes, css

I'd like to edit the dark Yaru theme for Ubuntu 20.04 (specifically the bright orange color on highlighted/selected items).  from other questions here I think I have to edit `/usr/share/themes/Yaru/gtk-3.20/gtk.css`, but the entire file is:

```
@import url("resource:///com/ubuntu/themes/Yaru/3.20/gtk.css");
```

What is `resource:///com/ubuntu/themes/Yaru/3.20/gtk.css` and how do I edit it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a file `gtk.gresource` in the same directory. It contains all packed theme files. `resource:///com/ubuntu/themes/Yaru/3.20/gtk.css` refers to `gtk.css` file packed inside this file.

You can view a list of all packed files with a command

```
gresource list gtk.gresource
```

You can unpack a particular file using a command eg.

```
gresource extract gtk.gresource /com/ubuntu/themes/Yaru/3.20/gtk.css >somefile.css
```

Note that the contents of the file is extracted to stdout so you have to redirect it to some other file.

I don't know however how to pack the files again into `gtk.gresource` after editing. But you don't have to pack them, you can unpack all files from `gtk.gresource` file and leave them in unpacked form.

I recommend however that you don't edit the Yaru theme in place because your changes might be overwritten when the theme's files are updated. Make a copy, change the theme's name (you must edit `index.theme` file in theme's main dir) to something that is unlikely to be used by standard themes (I use "My Theme" for example) and edit the copy.