# How do I add scrollbar up/down buttons to my scrollbar in all applications?

Tags: scrollbar

Old threads cite ubuntu 18.04 as just open your theme's CSS

Well my CSS is only

```
@import url("resource:///com/ubuntu/themes/Yaru-bark-dark/3.0/gtk.css");
```

That's it. I think it's downloading the theme from somewhere? I don't know how to get there to edit it.

Day 2 of Ubuntu and the fact there's no arrows makes that really difficult. Like other threads cited, a Thunderbird client with 15000 emails makes you jump down 18 months if you do the "click in empty space below the scroller" and it's near impossible to finely scroll by a few items at a time. Down arrow navigation ends up marking everything as read in the process. And no, my mouse doesn't have a scroll wheel. That's why I want the arrows.

So what are the steps for the latest Ubuntu to get scroll arrows back? I'm on whatever the latest is. 22 something. I don't know how to find it, there's no Control Panel that I'm aware of or My PC specs to look that up.

Comment: You can use this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1468743/1698042) to export the gtk.css file and add up/dn stepper

Comment: No, that does not fix thunderbird at all. It did improve libre office, and maybe firefox (haven't restarted that app yet), but thunderbird is immune to those changes.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/1261165/1611143) should give you a better idea about the location of the css files used.